# [UWP]Running Background Tasks for more than 30sec

Tags: uwp, background-task

In UWP, I have a timer task which runs every 15 minutes.
The Background Tasks for timer trigger is allowed to run only for 30 seconds.
But, in some cases I need the background task to run for more than 30 seconds.
Also, this is required when the app is in suspended state.
Any suggestions how this can be achieved?

Comment: The system could not make the exception and let the task to run more than 30 secs. I think it's better to make it finish within than limit.

Comment: You cannot bypass this, as it's an OS level restriction enforced on the Win devices. [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299103.aspx#BACKGROUND_TASK_RESOURCE_CONSTRAINTS)

Answer (score 3):

For long-running background tasks, there are three triggers: `MaintenanceTrigger`, `ApplicationTrigger` and `DeviceUseTrigger`. You may use [MaintenanceTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.maintenancetrigger.aspx) if every 15 min is required. Its function is same as timer trigger. But

> Background tasks that use a maintenance trigger run only when the system is 
>   connected to AC power.

So like @kennyzx said, it's better to make it finished within 30s as background tasks are needed to be [lightweight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt299103.aspx#background_task_resource_constraints). It has a lot of additional resource constraints .Windows will terminate background task when memory or battery stays in a low level. For example, we shouldn't handle download with background task because it is long time operation, we should use BackgroundTransfer in that situation . if we need to deal with some simple operations like pushing a notification or updating a tile, background task is perfect . Keeping background execution to a minimum ensures the best user experience with foreground apps and battery life.